# Get player to jump with touch screen control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello and thanks for reading this post.

I have 2 objects: A player Object and a JumpButton Object.

The Player object is the player. ofc. The JumpButton Object is an object that I want to make the player jump when you use a touch screen device aka android phone.

This is my Script that is assinged to my JumpButton: using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JumpButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject player;
public GameObject JumpButton;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    player = GameObject.Find ("player");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if ((Input.touchCount == 1) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)) 
    {

    }
  }
}
```

This is the script that allows me to control the player with arrow keys.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RobotController : MonoBehaviour {
//This will be our maximum speed as we will always be multiplying by 1
public float maxSpeed = 2f;
public GameObject player;
public GameObject sprite;
//a boolean value to represent whether we are facing left or not
bool facingLeft = true;
//a value to represent our Animator
Animator anim;
//to check ground and to have a jumpforce we can change in the editor
bool grounded = true;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundRadius = 1f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public float jumpForce = 300f;
private bool isOnGround = false;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        isOnGround = true;  
    }

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    isOnGround = false;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    player = GameObject.Find("player");

    //set anim to our animator
    anim = GetComponent <Animator>();
}


void FixedUpdate () {
    //set our vSpeed
    //set our grounded bool

    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    //set ground in our Animator to match grounded
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");//Gives us of one if we are moving via the arrow keys
    //move our Players rigidbody
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);   
    //set our speed
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed",Mathf.Abs (move));
    //if we are moving left but not facing left flip, and vice versa
    if (move > 0 && !facingLeft) {

        Flip ();
    } else if (move < 0 && facingLeft) {
        Flip ();
    }

}

void Update(){
    if ((isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) || (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))) {
        anim.SetBool("Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
    }

    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    }
    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    }
}



//flip if needed
void Flip(){
    facingLeft = !facingLeft;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

As you can see, then I managed to make the player move on arrow keys, but how can I make it jump when I hit the jump button (touch Screen press), as on an Android Phone?

I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is how to handle input, try this code we will make ray from camera to mousepos in screen and check tag to see what we hitted

```
public class handleInput: MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                if (hit.collider.tag=="jumpbutton"){
                    jump();
                }      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and for the jumping part you can do this , adding a force to player to send him up and gravity should pull him down

```
if (grounded == true)
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up* jumpSpeed);

        grounded = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But nothing happends when I then click on the button.

Comment: did you add a jumpbutton tag to your button gameobject

Comment: I had what you can see in the code above. Remind that im new to this so the tag, how do i place that